# How to retrieve timezone offset from GMT+0 in php?

Tags: php, timezone-offset

I am no expert in php. I know timezones are [supported](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in PHP.

For a given timezone TZ supported by PHP, I need to retrieve the offset (i.e., number of hours and minutes to add or substract) to a known UTC (i.e. GMT+0) to get that time in the TZ zone.

How can I achieve this? Ultimately, I need to get those offsets for all supported timezones in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just set the default timezone to what you need?

Comment: I need the reverse operation.

Comment: See my single line answer **[below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40204648/4134066)**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a simple example how to get timezone offset in seconds:

```
$dtz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia');
$time_in_sofia = new DateTime('now', $dtz);
echo $dtz->getOffset( $time_in_sofia );
```

to display it in the format GMT+x:

```
$offset = $dtz->getOffset( $time_in_sofia ) / 3600;
echo "GMT" . ($offset < 0 ? $offset : "+".$offset);
```

[working example](http://codepad.org/YPsh2xPA)

Comment: @Raceimaztion **do not approve invalid edits**.  Reviewing is a serious responsibility and requires that you pay careful attention, you have approved 101 edits in sequence which is not credible.

Comment: Please note that the actual answer format is wrong:
The answer states that the offset uses the GMT standard, while instead it uses the UTC standard.

GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) is affected by summer time, meaning that in summer GMT will go from UTC+0 to UTC+1.
For example, a country like Italy, which has GMT+1 or UTC+1 will get UTC+2 in summer time.

Testing this code with 'Europe/Rome' returned "GMT+2" which is incorrect, this code instead returns the UTC value

Comment: @Teneff, Could you please write one-liner? It could be more handy in some cases... :)

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani No, GMT does not change during summer. The difference between GMT and UTC is that UTC is controlled by an atomic clock so UTC is sort of a tractable approximation to GMT.

Comment: As pointed out above GMT does not change the the time zone is switched between GMT and BST(British Summer Time) which is equivilent to GMT+1 Hour.  For the most part UTC and GMT are as good as identical.

Answer (score 29):

This will be useful for converting offset values into GMT format without any calculation

```
<?php

  //target time zone
  $target_time_zone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

  //find kolkata time 
  $date_time = new DateTime('now', $target_time_zone);

  //get the exact GMT format
  echo 'GMT '.$date_time->format('P');
```

Comment: simple using the inbuilt api. sweet!

Comment: This is the BEST answer!

Comment: This is not correct, just tested for "America/Sao_Paulo" and it's giving GMT -02:00 when it should currently be GMT -03:00

Comment: @James The timezone America/Sao_Paulo is currently at UTC-3. This was a change from the originally planned timezone defined in 2017 (which by now would have had DST kick in, putting us at UTC-2);

Comment: How to extract hours and minute separately from the output?

Answer (score 14):

This will get you the standard offset (not the one **in *or* out of [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DST)** [depending on the time of year]):

```
function getStandardOffsetUTC($timezone)
{
    if($timezone == 'UTC') {
        return '';
    } else {
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
        $transitions = $timezone->getTransitions(time() - 86400*365, time());

        foreach ($transitions as $transition)
        {
            if ($transition['isdst'])
            {
                continue;
            }

            return sprintf('UTC %+03d:%02u', $transition['offset'] / 3600, abs($transition['offset']) % 3600 / 60);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getStandardOffsetUTC('Europe/Sofia'); // UTC +02:00
```

You can get a peek at the differences [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Great answer. There's a typo in this code on the foreach line -- an extra closing bracket.

Comment: Actually this answer is fairly problematic: fetching all transitions is very slow, taking up lots of memory. If you're doing this for more than a single timezone, it's probably a bad idea. A better implementation might fetch only transitions for the last year -- see the comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php which for once actually make sense (this is a PHP 5.3 feature AIUI).

Comment: @GeorgeLund: Yeah, I wrote this for 5.2 at the time, feel free to update it. :-)

Comment: Updated, I feel like supporting 5.3 is not really needed anymore :). Not sure what that array_reverse and preserving keys was for, please verify. Seems to work OK

Answer (score 11):

It is possible just by the following single line.

```
echo (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone( 'Asia/Kabul' )))->format('P');
```

Comment: Awesome. Just one question, how to extract hours and minute separately from the output?

Comment: Use explode(":", $value) where $value is what is returned from the above code.

Answer (score 3):

For all supported timezones in PHP:

```
$timezone_offsets = array();

foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $timezone_identifier)
{
    $date_time_zone = new DateTimeZone($timezone_identifier);
    $date_time = new DateTime('now', $date_time_zone);
    $timezone_offsets[$timezone_identifier] = $date_time_zone->getOffset($date_time);
}

print_r($timezone_offsets);
```